# getting the shape for the input_shape parameter LSTM

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

Is there a way to get the shape automatically for the input_shape parameter in LSTM, then to set that shape to the input_shape parameter.
I want to be able to have the Recurrent Neural Network to set the input shape automatically, depending on the shape of the data.
Thanks.

```
    dataset_train = pd.read_csv(dataset_path)
    
    training_set = dataset_train.iloc[:, :].values

    from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
    sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    training_set_scaled = sc.fit_transform(x)

    
    print(len(training_set_scaled))
    print(len(dataset_train))

    X_train = []
    y_train = []
    for i in range(past_days, len(training_set_scaled) - future_days + 1):
        X_train.append(training_set_scaled[i - past_days:i, 0])
        y_train.append(training_set_scaled[i + future_days - 1:i + future_days, 0])
    X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)

    
    ## Building and Training the RNN

    from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout

    ### Initialising the RNN


    regressor = Sequential()

    ### Adding the first LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation

    regressor.add(LSTM(units=50, input_shape= (?) , return_sequences=True))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

    ### Adding a second LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation

    regressor.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

    ### Adding a third LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation

    regressor.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

    ### Adding a fourth LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation

    regressor.add(LSTM(units=50))
    regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

    ### Adding the output layer

    regressor.add(Dense(units=1))

    ### Compiling the RNN

    regressor.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know what data you're going to be training/testing the model on, this shouldn't be a challenge. You just have to pick one data point from your dataset. If your data is in NumPy/Tensor/Pandas, you can get it's shape using `x.shape()` . You don't have to worry about the batch size, this is something that Keras will automatically pick on.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use `input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]`. That is assuming your input shape is correct, and can pass through the neural net.

Comment: I got the following error:  str(x.shape.as_list()))
ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 0]

Comment: so you input shape is 0? like i said, that will only work if you have the proper input shape

Comment: what's your input shape?

Comment: This is your problem. You're not ready to automatically infer the shape because your input is wrong

Comment: Again, your input is wrong. No matter what you put in `input_shape` will throw an error